# Enabling ssl on local network with using the CA signed certs(not self signed certificates)

Tags: linux, ssl-certificate

I want to implement ssl connection to the app running in the VM as container on the local network. How can I achieve it without using the self signed certs??

Comment: "without using the CA signed certs" *AND* "without using the self-signed certs"? Who is signing then?

Comment: thanks for pointing it out, I have edited my question. I want to use CA signed certs in the local network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have completed the setup by using pi-hole and Nginx reverse proxy